# form for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form like this

```
<%= form_tag organizations_add_user_path, :method => :put do %>
  <label><h2>Add user</h2></label>
  <%= text_field_tag :nick %>
<% end %>
```

I want this form to process the action `add_user` from `Organizations` controller

My routes are this

```
resources :users, :sessions, :documents, :storages, :organizations

match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'
match 'profile' => 'users#profile'
match 'organizations/add_user' => 'organizations#add_user', :via => :post
```

But when I submit my form, the app sends me to `update` method form organizations, with Organization id as `add_user`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a route for '**post**' method but used '**put**' method in the form.

```
<%= form_tag organizations_add_user_path, :method => :post do %>
  <label><h2>Add user</h2></label>
  <%= text_field_tag :nick %>
<% end %>
```